# Latency time for logic gates?

Tags: verilog, logic-gates, system-verilog, latency

today I learn about latency especially Tpdhl (high to low) and Tpdlh (low to high).

My question is, let's suppose a gate has Tpdhl=8 and Tpdlh=6 so how much time it will take to process the input if it was uninitialised at first?

Does that rely on the input if it's 0 or 1? please help me

Comment: If the input is a rising edge then it's 6. If it's a falling edge then it's 8. It really is as simple as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These delays assume a known state. There is no such thing as an uninitialized in real hardware, but if you are asking how simulation in Verilog/SystemVerilog interprets it; X→1 is a rise, X→0 is a fall.

Comment: By X you mean the output right?

Comment: Verilog has a few different ways of propagation delays, but yes, a change on the *output* is the most basic.